# Style input elements differently based on whether they received focus using keyboard or mouse, using pure CSS

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am asked to try to style input elements differently based on whether they received focus using keyboard or mouse, using pure CSS.
Below is my attempt but it is not working on Chrome and windows 11. The green border is always shown, regardless of whether I select the controls by mouse or by tabbing to them, whereas I want to show green border on focus done by mouse-click, and crimson border for focus done by keyboard tabbing:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test focus visible css rule</title>
    <style>
      label {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 1em;
      }

      input:focus-visible {
        outline: 3px solid crimson;
        border-radius: 3px;
      }

      input:focus {
        outline: 2px solid green;
        border-radius: 3px;
      }

      select:focus-visible {
        border: 3px dashed crimson;
        border-radius: 3px;
        outline: none;
      }

      select:focus {
        border: 2px dashed green;
        border-radius: 3px;
        outline: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <p>Which flavor would you like to order?</p>
      <label>Full Name: <input name="firstName" type="text" /></label>
      <label
        >Flavor:
        <select name="flavor">
          <option>Cherry</option>
          <option>Green Tea</option>
          <option>Moose Tracks</option>
          <option>Mint Chip</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what do you want?

Comment: I have edited the original post to make the question more clear.

Comment: The https://blog.chromium.org/2020/09/giving-users-and-developers-more.html example uses a polyfill script. If I delete the polyfill script, the example does not work!

Comment: I don't think it is possible without `js`